# Permission denied when creating a CA in CentOS linux

Tags: openssl, centos, vagrant, x509certificate, ca

I've followed the [vagrant getting started guide](https://www.vagrantup.com/intro/getting-started/index.html) for installing vagrant and getting CentOS up and running. I now need to create a CA authority (so that I can self sign certs for use with docker - hello-world is failing to pull.) To do this, I am following [this document](https://www.golinuxcloud.com/generate-self-signed-certificate-openssl/) but I am falling foul of the **Create Certificate Authority (CA)** section which says to run this command:

```
openssl req -new -x509 -key private/mykey.pem -days 365 > mycert.pem
```

I get `permission denied`, so I tried with `sudo`:

```
sudo openssl req -new -x509 -key private/mykey.pem -days 365 > mycert.pem
```

Which also produces `permission denied`.

Given I am starting up my vagrant-based centos with the standard `vagrant up` and `vagrant ssh` commands, what should I do to acquire the requisite permissions in order to run the `openssl req` command?

Answer (score 4):

All steps in the document that you have linked are executed as root.

Become root with:

```
sudo su
```

And then execute the command again:

```
openssl req -new -x509 -key private/mykey.pem -days 365 > mycert.pem
```